# Has Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu been recognized as a form of Jiu-Jitsu in Japan?

Tags: jujutsu, brazilian-jiu-jitsu, style

In North America, Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu practice and instruction is quite different from what is found in schools of Jiu-Jitsu that describe themselves as Japanese.

Are the two martial arts still related? Is training in one still recognized in the other?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most people acknowledge that, given that Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu is derived from Maeda's teachings in Kodokan Judo (then known as Kodokan Jiu-Jitsu in the appropriate romanization of the time), it is recognized as a derivative of Judo, but they have each long-since taken very different paths.

Jujutsu (the modernly accepted romanization of 柔術) is a broad term used to describe a large number of various styles/schools (*ryuha*) of unarmed combat, and the rather generic description of "Japanese Jujutsu" used by dojo marketing gurus is usually just a collection of common techniques from those schools mixed with Judo, ***or***, in rare cases, a marketing ploy to make a single *ryuha* appear more familiar (People may not recognize, for instance, *Yagyu Shingan-ryu Heiho* [poor example, since most people would doubt it's even jujutsu at first glance], but the broad term of "Jujutsu" or, with the modern upsurge of BJJ, "Japanese Jujutsu" [to differentiate] is easily more accessible). Brazilian Jiu-jitsu is very distantly related to these arts.

Comment: this pretty much sums it up!  great answer.   as a practitioner of both,  i must say, they are pretty much completely different arts, I cannot see a reputable school of either recognizing grades from the other.  That would be like a tkd practitioners rank being recognized by an Aikido school.